# Swift application crashing in simulation, but works when ran from Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-workspace

I have Xcode workspace with two projects in it. First one is Alamofire (as git submodule) and second one is my project. It looks like this:

[image: project structure]

These are my build phases:

[image: project structure]

Nothing fancy in my project, just added CoreLocation.framework, Alamofire.framework, and then tested CLLocationManager and threw some Alamofire requests in AppDelegate.swift.

So, when I build and run project from the Xcode, application launches fine and I can do whatever I want. But when I stop it from the Xcode and try to run it in the simulator (every device tested) it simply shows launch screen and then crashes without message. What could be the problem here? I'm guessing it's something about build phases and project build schemes but I don't know.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app on simulator?

Comment: Yeah, It launches again fine, it asks me for the permission to use my location, I quit it from Xcode then I try to run it from simulator and it crashes.

Comment: There have been some changes to CoreLocation in iOS 8. But not sure it has anything to with your issue. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization

Comment: Have you tried setting the Location in simulator? Under menu Debug > Location... I remember vaguely having to reset the simulator early on while using Xcode 6 beta, after having some issues with Core location. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting location in simulator and in the build scheme, none of them works. I get location normally when I run the app from Xcode, and I use `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`